# Empty title when inserting a Google Task with google apis node.js client

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-tasks

When I use this code, a new task is created but the title is empty

```js
const service = google.tasks({ version: "v1", auth })
service.tasks.insert(
    {
        tasklist: <ID_OF_YOUR_TASK_LIST>,
        title: "hello"

    },
    (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err)
        console.log(res)
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `resource` instead of `requestBody`, it will work too.

Tested on Node 13.4.0, works as expected

```js
function insertTask(auth) {
  const service = google.tasks({version: 'v1', auth});
  service.tasks.insert({
    "tasklist": "___ID___",
    "resource": {
      "title": "___TITLE___"
    }
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.error('The API returned an error: ' + err);
  });
}
```

### Reference

[Google Tasks API > Tasks > insert](https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks/insert)

Answer (score 0):

I found after a while that you need to specify body parameters in a `requestBody` object.
The code below is working

```js
const service = google.tasks({ version: "v1", auth })
service.tasks.insert(
    {
        tasklist: <ID_OF_YOUR_TASK_LIST>,,
        requestBody: { // ! important !
            title: "hello"
        }
    },
    (err, res) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err)
        console.log(res)
    }
)
```